# Synthetic Propane Manufacture

Tags: energy

Methane (CH4) is available naturally.  Propane (C3H8) is derived from Methane.  Is there a process for synthesizing propane applicable to a micro-farm environment?

Comment: CAn you describe your (potential) application in more detail? Do you have a methane source, what is it? Why do you want to create propane, storage?

Comment: The [Motunui synthetic petrol plant](https://www.ipenz.org.nz/heritage/itemdetail.cfm?itemid=68) in NZ had a high-level goal of methane to petrol, but it was complex and expensive. On a farm you may be better off fermenting simple alcohols and burning those, rather than working with alkanes.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no sustainable method to turn methane into propane, but I must admit I'm no expert on this topic. I do know that it is possible to use  use CO<sub>2</sub>, water and electricity to generate methane on a small scale. When the electricity comes from (the spare capacity of) sustainable energy sources then this process is sustainable and can be used to  reduce CO<sub>2</sub>. More info on this [on this site](http://www.etogas.com/en/the-challenge).

Also, in [this article](http://www.technologyreview.com/news/407312/a-portable-refinery-powered-by-garbage/) they claim they built a small portable refinary that turns

> plastics, paper, and other residual waste into methane and low-grade propane.

However, from the article it isn't clear to me how the process works exactly and how sustainable it really is. The article does say that the refinery requires diesel fuel for the first hours to run.